# Install Oracle 11g on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, oracle

I've been trying for days now to get Oracle 11g installed on Ubuntu 14.04.
There are a number of notes / tutorials on this, and I've tried more than ten of them, but I keep encountering the same issue once running the Oracle installer, at the 'Link Binaries' step it always complains with this message:

```
Error in invoking target 'install' of makefile '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/ctx/lib/ins_ctx.mk'. See '/u01/app/oraInventory/logs/installActions2015-01-07_03-25-51OM.log' for details.
```

In the log file it says

```
INFO: //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.5: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

From the tens of forums I've trawled through, most seem to suggest that the problem is that Ubuntu comes with libstdc++6 installed but Oracle 11gR2 requires libstdc++5.

So, as suggested in many places, I've done something similar to the following, although I had to dig around a bit to find the right versions:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-3.3/libstdc++5_3.3.6-17ubuntu1_amd64.deb
dpkg-deb -x libstdc++5_3.3.6-17ubuntu1_amd64.deb ia64-libs
sudo cp ia64-libs/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5.0.7 /usr/lib64/
cd /usr/lib64/
sudo ln -s libstdc++.so.5.0.7 libstdc++.so.5

wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/ia32-libs/ia32-libs_2.7ubuntu6.1_amd64.deb
dpkg-deb -x ia32-libs_2.7ubuntu6.1_amd64.deb ia32-libs
sudo cp ia32-libs/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.5.0.7 /usr/lib32/
cd /usr/lib32
sudo ln -s libstdc++.so.5.0.7 libstdc++.so.5
```

But it... just... doesn't... work!

I've rebooted etc to make sure this take effect, but no luck. This is on a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04, with nothing but some proxy settings setup, and java 7 installed.

I've created a separate **oracle user** (and an oinstall and dba group), and I su to the oracle user before running the **runInstaller** script from the extracted oracle download.

**Does anyone have a step-by-step guide applicable to Ubuntu 14.04 and Oracle 11gR2?**

---

**Update Fri 09 Jan 2015**

Some more info that may be relevant.

In **/usr/lib32/** I have this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     18 Jan  7 15:22 libstdc++.so.5 -> libstdc++.so.5.0.7
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 737192 Jan  7 15:21 libstdc++.so.5.0.7
```

In **/usr/lib64/** I have this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     42 Jan  7 13:46 libc_nonshared.a -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     48 Jan  7 13:47 libpthread_nonshared.a -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread_nonshared.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     18 Jan  7 14:52 libstdc++.so.5 -> libstdc++.so.5.0.7
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 829792 Jan  7 14:51 libstdc++.so.5.0.7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     40 Jan  7 13:47 libstdc++.so.6 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

In **~/.bashrc** (for the oracle user) I have this:

```
export TMP=/tmp
export TMPDIR=$TMP
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
export ORACLE_SID=mydb
export PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib32:/usr/lib64:$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
export CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib:$CLASSPATH
```

Comment: Try the command and check su - root, touch /etc/rac_on after doing so restart the dbca. Hope this helps in fixing the issue.

Comment: Thanks vembutech. I'm not quite sure what you meant, but for the hell of it I added the /etc/rac_on file (it didn't exist). Note that I get the ins_ctx.mk makefile error during the installation itself, during the 'Link Binaries' step, so I'm not sure I've even got dbca installed at that point.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same "undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'" error with Oracle 11g R2 on Debian 8 (Jessie). I solved it with the solution [found here](http://www.uxora.com/oracle/dba/23-oracle-installation-errors-and-fixes):

Define the relevant directories:

```sh
ORACLE_HOME="/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1"
mkfile="$ORACLE_HOME/ctx/lib/ins_ctx.mk"
```

Create a short C wrapper:

```C
cat << __EOF__ > /tmp/memcpy_wrap.c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

asm (".symver wrap_memcpy, memcpy@GLIBC_2.14");
void *wrap_memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n) {
    return memcpy(dest, src, n);
}
__EOF__
```

Edit the make file to use this wrapper and compile it:

```C
sed -i -e 's/\$(INSO_LINK)/\$(INSO_LINK) -Wl,--wrap=memcpy_wrap \$(ORACLE_HOME)\/ctx\/lib\/memcpy_wrap.o/g' "$mkfile"
gcc -c /tmp/memcpy_wrap.c -o ${ORACLE_HOME}/ctx/lib/memcpy_wrap.o && rm /tmp/memcpy_wrap.c
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked this out.  I'm new to Ubuntu (just installed 14.04 on an old server) and have been trying to crack the memcpy@GLIBC_2.14 issue as well.   I've followed the same notes, etc you refer to above.

It would appear that `libstdc++.so.5.0.7` ends up in multiple places i.e. `/usr/lib64`, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.  When I work through all of the various links, etc it would appear that the `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.5` library is actually pointing to the version sitting in `/usr/lib/x86_65-linux-gnu`. This is significantly newer than the one you (and I) download.

I took a copy of the original `libstdc++.so.5.0.7` in the `/usr/lib/x86-64` and then copied the file we downloaded into this directory and repointed the `libstdc++.so.5` link to the new version of the file.

It moved on. Now, I'm getting issues with Enterprise Manager, will come back to this.